Location shift of two distributions
Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let $\mathbb{Y}$ be the support of $Y$ and take a function $f:\mathbb{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Consider the distribution  of $$
X+f(Y)  \text{ conditional on $Y=y$}
$$
and the distribution of
$$
X+f(Y) \text{ conditional on $Y=y'$}
$$
Is it correct to say that these two distributions will have all equal central moments except the mean?
This is correct when $X$ has, for instance, a Normal distribution. However, I am not sure if it holds generically.

You might want to ask about cental moments, because $X + 1$ and $X + 2$ do not have the same second moment, even when $X$ is standard normal.

That is true, thanks

Yes, the conditional higher-order central moments are all the same
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the conditional expectation has the following form:
$$\begin{align}
\mu(y) &\equiv \mathbb{E}[X+f(Y) | Y=y] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[X | Y=y] + \mathbb{E}[f(Y) | Y=y] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[X] + f(y), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Using the independence condition again, you then have conditional higher-order central moments given by:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X+f(Y) - \mu(y))^k | Y=y] 
&= \mathbb{E}[(X+f(Y) - \mathbb{E}[X] - f(y))^k | Y=y] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(X+f(y) - \mathbb{E}[X] - f(y))^k | Y=y] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^k | Y=y] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^k], \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
which is just the $k$th higher-order central moment of $X$.  As you can see, this does not depend on the conditioning value $y$, so the conditional higher-order central moments are all the same regardless of the conditioning value.

If $f$ is identical function:
We want to find:
$$\mathbb{E}[(X + Y - \mathbb{E}[X + Y])^n \mid Y = y]$$
Since $X,Y$ are independent,
$$\mathbb{E}[(X + Y - \mathbb{E}[X + Y])^n \mid Y = y]=\mathbb{E}[(X + Y - (\mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]))^n \mid Y = y]$$
rewrite it as:
$$\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X]) + (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]))^n \mid Y = y]$$
Using binomial theorem:
$$
(x+y)^n=\binom{n}{0} x^n y^0+\binom{n}{1} x^{n-1} y^1+\binom{n}{2} x^{n-2} y^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1} x^1 y^{n-1}+\binom{n}{n} x^0 y^n
$$
when $k \neq 0$
$$\mathbb{E}[\binom{n}{k} (X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{n-k} (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])^k|Y=y]=\binom{n}{k} (X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{n-k} \mathbb{E}[(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])^k|Y=y]=\binom{n}{k} (X - \mathbb{E}[X])^{n-k}\times 0=0$$
Thus
$$\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X]) + (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]))^n \mid Y = y]=\mathbb{E}[\binom{n}{n} (X - \mathbb{E}[X])^n(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])^0|Y=y]=\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^n|Y=y]=(X - \mathbb{E}[X])^n$$
If $f$ is any other function, the results are the same.
